# How to get count of records based on values in a column for all tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have list of tables in Oracle which has values like below

REF_table1

```
System(Col 1)  Description(Col 2) 
ABC             abba
PQR             puqar
XYZ             end
ABC             abba
ABC             abba
PQR             puqar
```

I want to retrieve count of records by System(col 1) for all tables which start with REF

```
TableName    ABC   PQR   XYZ
REF_table1   3      2     1
REF_table2   6      2     5
REF_table3   4      3     7
```

I have tried a query but had no luck

```
DECLARE
   nbr NUMBER := 0;
   total NUMBER := 0;
   stmt VARCHAR2(100):= 'SELECT COUNT(System),System FROM ';
BEGIN
   -- Iterate over all tables that fit your criteria
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables t WHERE /*t.owner = '#####' and*/ t.table_name LIKE 'REF_%' and t.owner ='someone') LOOP
      nbr := 0;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt || i.table_name INTO nbr;
      total := total + nbr;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('total : '||total);
END;
```

Comment: Check out the pivot command. You want to convert columns to rows, wich is exactly what pivot does. Chris Saxon wrote an excellent blog about it here: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Thank you. Yes that would be second step. However, first I have to calculate records(group by) for every table having System(col 1) and then pivot it.

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT Statement containing PIVOT clause composed of columns with names `col1`, `col2` and `col3` may suit well for your case. This way, you can loop through those columns with their indexes within a dynamic query by the contribution of an array variable ( `col OWA.NC_ARR` ) :

```
SQL > SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL > DECLARE
        col   OWA.NC_ARR;
        total INT := 0;   
        stmt  VARCHAR2(4000):= 
          ' PIVOT
            (
              COUNT(*) FOR System IN ( ''ABC'' AS COL1, ''PQR'' AS COL2, ''XYZ'' AS COL3 )
            )';
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TableName    ABC   PQR   XYZ   Total');  
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name 
               FROM user_tables 
              WHERE table_name LIKE 'REF_%'
              ORDER BY table_name ) 
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(RPAD(i.table_name,13,' '));
    FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COL'|| j ||' FROM ' || i.table_name ||stmt INTO col(j);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(RPAD(col(j),6,' '));

      total := total + col(j);
    END LOOP;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(total);
      total := 0;      
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a54781547e30ce8e65f03faee375bff)</kbd>

Comment: I am getting error on line 'FOR j IN 1..3 LOOP' it says "table or view does not exist". I am using all_tables instead of user_tables because user_tables is empty in my case. However "select * from all_tables" works fine for me. Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: it doesn't matter both are synonyms, user_tables is spesific to your current user. You can replace `FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'REF_%'` with `FROM all_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'REF_%' AND OWNER=<the desired schema>`. Btw, are you connecting to SYS or SYSTEM ..? @um123

Comment: Btw, owner name should be capitalized, e.g. use `and t.owner ='SOMEONE'` instead of `and t.owner ='someone'` @um123